# How do I rearrange the execution order of solvers in Mixed Reality Toolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

MRTK's Solver documentation says that you can "stack" solvers on the same object and their effects become cumulative.

The Known Issues section implies that you can control which order the solvers are evaluated in, and that this can cause differences in behavior.

How do I change the evaluation order for two solvers on the same GameObject?

Comment: probably they mean you can change their [Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html). Shortly I also discovered [this Attribute plugin](https://github.com/azixMcAze/Unity-ExecutionOrder) which lets you controll the execution orders directly in the scripts which is really cool

Comment: Oh man, I hadn't even thought of using the script execution order. Is that really what the documentation intends? You'd like it would be more explicit about that.

Comment: I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They update in the order they appear on the game object in the inspector, top to bottom (as long as GetComponents continues to return them in that order!)  You can rearrange component order by clicking the gear icon for a component in the inspector, and choosing 'Move Up' or 'Move Down'.  Hope this helps!